# SOAP API method for SSRS report usage statistics

Tags: asp.net, soap, reporting-services

I've developed a .Net web application using the SOAP API (ReportingService2010) to list details on SSRS reports. 
For the next step, I need to get some usage statistics such as which reports are accessed the most, which reports are accessed most frequently etc.

I know you can get some of this from the ExecutionLog table, but I'd like to avoid the SQL approach. Is there a way to get usage statistics like this directly through the SOAP API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope.  Best you can get from the stock API is snapshot/cache history information.  You could, however, extend the existing API (pulling the information from ExecutionLogStorage).  Even though you'd still be building the methods yourself, at least you could wrap them up nicely within the existing webservice.